# How to get the bound item from within an ASP.NET repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I have to set a LinkButton's OnClientClick attribute but I don't know what this value  is until the LinkButton is bound to. I'm trying to set the value when the repeater binds, but I can't workout how to get the 'boundItem/dataContext' value...

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton  Text="HelloWorld" ID="Hyper1" runat="server" OnDataBinding="Repeater1_DataBinding" >
        </asp:LinkButton> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = new List<TestObject>();
    list.Add(new TestObject() {TestValue = "testing1"});
    list.Add(new TestObject() { TestValue = "testing2" });
    list.Add(new TestObject() { TestValue = "testing3" });

    this.Repeater1.DataSource = list;
    this.Repeater1.DataBind();
}

public void Repeater1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var link = sender as HyperLink;
    //link.DataItem ???
}
```

Is there anyway to find out what the current rows bound item is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you need to use ItemDataBound event. It provides RepeaterItemEventArgs argument which has DataItem available

```
this.Repeater1.ItemDataBound += Repeater1_ItemDataBound;

void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var dataItem = e.Item.DataItem;
}
```

Comment: You might put the "var dataItem = ..." part inside of an if statement that checks whether this is a Item, Header, or Footer record.  For example, if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)) { ... }

Comment: `DataBinding` is the correct event since he wants to affect the `HyperLink` control directly. It sounds like he doesn't know how to evaluate the field value to apply it to the `HyperLink` control.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are trying to get the value for the row that is currently being databound?

You can change your function to:

```
public void Repeater1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    var link = sender as HyperLink;
    string valueYouWant = Eval("TestValue").ToString();

    // You could then assign the HyperLink control to whatever you need
    link.Target = string.Format("yourpage.aspx?id={0}", valueYouWant);
}
```

`valueYouWant` now has the value of the field `TestValue` for the current row that is being databound.  Using the `DataBinding` event is the best way to do this compared to the `ItemDataBound` because you don't have to search for a control and localize the code specifically to a control instead of a whole template.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN library had this as a sample event handler:

```
public void BindData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal l = (Literal) sender;
    DataGridItem container = (DataGridItem) l.NamingContainer;
    l.Text = ((DataRowView) container.DataItem)[column].ToString();

}
```

(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.databinding.aspx)

As you can see it is a simple demonstration of how to access the data item and get data from it. Adapting this to your scenario is an exercise left to the reader. :)